# Python - threading.Timer stays alive after calling cancel() method

Tags: python, multithreading

I noticed the following behavior in the following code (using threading.Timer class):

```
import threading

def ontimer():
    print threading.current_thread()

def main():
    timer = threading.Timer(2, ontimer)
    timer.start()
    print threading.current_thread()
    timer.cancel()
    if timer.isAlive():
        print "Timer is still alive"
    if timer.finished:
        print "Timer is finished"


 if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

The output of the code is:

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 5836)>
Timer is still alive
Timer is finished
```

As We notice from the output, that the timer object is still alive and finished in the same time.

In fact, I would like to call a similar function hundreds of times, and I wonder whether those "living" timers may affect the performance.

I would like to stop or cancel the timer object in a proper way. Am I doing it right?

Thank you

Comment: Replace `timer.finished` with `timer.finished.is_set()`. The property `timer.finished` is not a boolean, it is an `_Event` object, so checking for `if timer.finished` is misleading (since that will always evaluate to True)

Comment: It just takes sometimes to considered "not alive", try to add sleep for 1 or 2 seconds after "timer.cancel()" and it will work properly .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `Timer` is a subclass of a `Thread` and its [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0792a0ad7f22/Lib/threading.py#l1049) is really simple. It waits the provided time by subscribing to the event `finished`.

So when you set the event by `Timer.cancel` it is guaranteed that the function does not get called. But it is not guaranteed that the Timer thread will directly continue (and exit).

So the point is that the thread of the timer can still be alive after the execution of `cancel`, but the function will not get executed. So checking for `finished` is safe, while testing for `Thread.is_alive` (newer API, use this!) is a race condition in this case.

Hint: You can verify this by placing a `time.sleep` after calling `cancel`. Then it will just print:

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 10872)>
Timer is finished
```

Answer (score 13):

You should use the [thread.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to wait until your timer's thread is really finished and cleaned.

```
import threading

def ontimer():
    print threading.current_thread()

def main():
    timer = threading.Timer(2, ontimer)
    timer.start()
    print threading.current_thread()
    timer.cancel()
    timer.join()         # here you block the main thread until the timer is completely stopped
    if timer.isAlive():
        print "Timer is still alive"
    else:
        print "Timer is no more alive"
    if timer.finished:
        print "Timer is finished"


 if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

This will display :

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 5836)>
Timer is no more alive
Timer is finished
```